# Is it possible to recover the content of a website no more available?

Tags: content, domain-registrar, database, dead-links, not-provided

Some years ago I charged some information and pictures on a web platform which let companies and freelancers keeping in touch for professional purposes.
 In the meanwhile the website stopped working. I guess the registrant did not renew the name domain registration since while typing it on the url, with the correct top-level extension, I get a totally different website, written in japanese, and the Whois record reports that it was registered on 2014.
The original website I'm referring to was created on 2009 instead, and it was still working at the end of 2012.

Now I need to recover information about the dates when I charged that material and its content, and / or the names of the companies which did apply (i.e. the list of the subscribed users who did interact within the site), but I can't access to this informations directly since the website it's unavailable.

So my question is:

*- is there a database available publicly where it is possible to recover the more information as possible about the content of a **dead website**?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it happened recently, then you can recover the content from Google cache. I have done this few times.

2 of my clients, forgot to renew the hosting account as result of it, all the source code deleted. I have recovered the content of the website from Goolge cache and rebuild the website. Most of them are static page.

If it is too old, like 2012, Impossible to recover the content.

Your last chance could be, try in www.archive.org

Comment: do you know if through archive.org it is also still possible to login to the website? (I can access pages where it's also possible clicking on the login button)

Comment: You can recover only the page content, i.e text / images of the your website. You can not recover the DB or the dynamic functionality of the website. You have to re-build by hiring some developers

Comment: so a developer can rebuild the login funcionality of a dead website just by working on the page content provided by archive.org? (without a permission by the original owner of the site?)